# Text not visible in mozilla

Tags: browser, mozilla

When I type my login credentials in mozilla the text is not visible but the credentials are submitted.However,When the same site is run in other browser everything works fine. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check style applied on the TextBox 
OR
Try to disable/reduce the padding.